# How to formulate a query to return documents where some boolean is true, else return documents with boolean false

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymodm

Please consider this document structure :

```
{
    _id:        <ObjectId>,
    version:    <int>
    approved:   <bool>
}
```

Now, consider this data-set :

```
[
    { version: 1, approved: false},
    { version: 2, approved: true},
    { version: 3, approved: false}
]
```

My goal would be to obtain the latest document version that is approved. That would be document version 2.

However, with this data-set :

```
[
    { version: 1, approved: false},
    { version: 2, approved: false},
    { version: 3, approved: false}
]
```

I'd expect to get the document of version 3 as the latest version.

How would I got about doing this through a single mongodb query?

For interest, I'm working through python with the pymongo and pymodm libraries. I'm assuming I'll have to do a raw MongoDB query so I think it won't matter much, but let me know if you know a better way to go about this!

Answer (score 1):

You can just sort it first by approved field after that by version field. Below is code how to get document as you wanted in mongo shell             `db.YourCollection.find().sort({approved:-1, version:-1}).next()`
  with pymongo     `doc = db['YourCollection'].find().sort([('approved',-1),('version',-1)]).next()`